# Divide Results into category using LIKE expression

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I run a query 'SELECT name, Age, city from Contacts' I get a few hundred rows.

I want to divide the results after the query executes, like this

```
**Name  Age   Status**
ABC   12    Young
DFD   14    Young
JGH   19    Mature
ITR   18    Mature
DLE   29    Adult
MJE   23    Adult
```

Here the Status field is computed depending on the Age eg:

Age >= 12 and <16   Status = Young
Age >=16 and <22    Status = Mature
Age >=23 and < 35   Status = Adult

and so on

How can I use best possible query to get the output if run on few hundred rows

Update: I also want to know that instead of numeric (Age) if I had to use this on a string field using LIKE operator, how would i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [case when](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms181765.aspx) construct can do what you're looking for.

Example taken form the MSDN:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, 'Price Range' = 
      CASE 
         WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
         WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
         ELSE 'Over $1000'
      END
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber ;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)